# multiple processes read/write fifo

Tags: c, multiprocessing

I need to write a multiple processes that write to FIFO, I'm wondering how to sync among them, do I need to write some lock, if yes then would that be slow as a process has to wait for the other to free the lock?
please let me know what other best way to achieve interprocess communication?

Comment: You need to describe your scenario in more detail. One particular issue is 'how big is each message'. If it is smaller than the size of a FIFO buffer (and is written with a single call to `write()`), then each message will be atomic, regardless of how many processes are using the FIFO. You also need to describe a little about whether the writing processes will all open the FIFO and keep it open until they're done, or whether they'll be opening and closing for each message. Is the data only going to the 'server', or is the server going to reply? If the server will reply, how will it reply?

Comment: You might be better off using sockets; each socket will be a bidirectional connection between the client and the server.  I'm assuming you do have a central server process and not some collection of programs all interworking at random, but your extra description should explain the 'process geometry' too.

Comment: How can I know the size of the FIFO buffer, the message will be 500k at most, is this size configurable. so what I have in mind is to have a FIFO that multiple processes will write to it and one process will read from it and send the content of it to the network.

Comment: 500 KiB is much bigger than the FIFO buffer size (possibly 100 times bigger).  You will have to ensure that you have proper concurrency control so that the processes can each write their message in turn without interference from the others.  You might use `fcntl()` (advisory) locking on a file so that processes can take turns.  Do you have a collection of processes writing to a single central process, all using the same FIFO to do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
"do I need to write some lock"
```

Well, probably yes.  If you are working with shared memory (pthreads, openmp) then you need to have some sort of read-write lock to prevent race conditions, data invalidation, etc.  If you are working with distributed memory then you'll want to think about some kind of reduction operation to get all of the data in one place.

```
"if yes then would that be slow as a process has to wait for the other to free the lock?"
```

That is up to you, the programmer.  It's easy to write slow, inefficient programs but will take some time to thing of ways to increase the program execution, speed, etc.  I might also add that where you think the performance bottlenecks should be aren't always where they actually occur.  It's a good idea to become best friends with a debugger and performance analyzer.

Here are some resources to get you started, I recommend doing research, writing code, and asking specific questions to get better help.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/

Also check out the 'related' questions to the right for some other great resources.